# how to search a div's children for a string

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="store">
<img class="act" src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">
<img src="imgT/02.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

I need to search the `#store`'s children and get the `src` attribute of the child which is consists of "05".

Something like:

```
var src = $("#store").children().find("05").attr("src");
alert (src);
```

I need `imgT/05.jpg` as result.

Comment: *..consists of "05"* - what? Where is 05 in your example?

Comment: @tymeJV - in the filename in the src attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a jquery wild card:

```
<div id="store">
    <img class="act" src="imgT/01.jpg" alt="img">
    <img src="imgT/05.jpg" alt="img">
    <img src="imgT/02.jpg" alt="img">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var src = $("#store").find("img[src*='05']").attr("src");
        alert(src);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @true its right. It is using some kind of regex, it is slower than no-regex  answers

Comment: This is probaly the worst performing  out of all the answers here. http://jsperf.com/adfadfadfadfaddddddf

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var img_list = $("#store").children()

    $.each(img_list,function(index,value){

          var src = $(value).attr("src");
          var _src = src.split(".")[0];
              _src = src.split("/");
          if (_src == "05"){
              alert(src)
          }

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#store").children().each(function() {
   var img = this.src.split('/').pop();
   if(img == '05.jpg') { 
      alert(this.src);
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v28cdyvo/1/

**Going further**
If the image extensions can't be determined we can just set up a regex to extract everything but numbers. Granted, that your images are stored will the file names as integers with 0's preprended to them. To do that you could this:

```
img = img.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v28cdyvo/

**In consideration** of the jQuery's `each()` method, you can't break out of the loop once you have found your match. You might think you can do a `break` statement, but that is illegal. If you have a lot of images, then this could affect performance. You can instead just use a basic for loop to traverse the array of objects and then break once you find it.

My code performs the fastest according to this [bechmark](http://jsperf.com/adfadfadfadfaddddddf)

Answer (score 1):

```
var src = $('#store img').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('src').match('05')
}).attr('src')
console.log(src);
```

Note that this will match `05` anywhere in the image src attribute.